# Open file with ShellExecute in the same application instance

Tags: vba, sharepoint, ms-word

Following [this guide](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00479_ShellExecute_Example.htm) I've built the following code to open a Word template file from SharePoint:

```
Sub open_file(ByVal control As IRibbonControl)

    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strAction As String
    Dim lngErr As Long

    strFile = "ms-word:nft|u|<file-path-url>|c|<save-location-url>" 
    strAction = "OPEN"

    lngErr = ShellExecute(0, strAction, strFile, "", "", 0)
    Debug.Print lngErr

End Sub
```

I'm able to have it successfully open as a new file from the template I have stored on SharePoint, but it is opening in a separate instance of Word, which causes issues with other Macros since it cannot be accessed.

How can I force it to open in the same instance of Word that I already have open?

Comment: by the out of curiosity what is |c| for?

Comment: I honestly don't remember where I saw the |c| used. Though, I've tried |s| too